# How to create json in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is my json sample string format:

```
 {"entry":{"user":{"id":5,"name":"testuser"},"startday":"2015-12-27","status":"New","total":0.0,"entries":[{"id":752,"typename":{"id":3,"name":"teste"},"typetypeissue":{"id":4},"user":{"id":5,"name":"testuser
 "},"activity":{"id":8,"name":"Design"},"time":4.0,"comments":"","Date":"2015-12-27"},{"id":750,"typename":{"id":2,"name":"teste1"},"typeissue":{"id":13},"user":{"id":5,"name":"testuser
 "},"activity":{"id":8,"name":"Design"},"time":4.0,"comments":"","Date":"2015-12-29"}]}}
```

the "entries" section is more than row values. please help me how to create a json format. the user enter the recods more than values "entries" section.

Comment: Create a *new* json!? In what way *new*?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: NSString *string = @"here your json string"; how to create json string in programmatically.

Comment: @luk2302 you should be more polite in your comments, Jan Greve just gave you a lesson.

Comment: @luk2302 Yelling and screaming with "?!" in first sentence is "you should try to help OP"? Really? You must be joking.

Comment: @luk2302 "OP is not new, he asked quite a lot of questions already." By that you mean 4 questions in the last 3 days, all of which are fairly low quality questions. And I, like JosipB thought that your first comment came off rude, or at the very least condescending.

Comment: @Stonz2 just give it a rest

Comment: here is the link. I have solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057281/creating-json-format-in-objective-c . some members are joking my question below. my question is some time your side wrong or simple logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *string = @"here your JSON string";
NSData *stringData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:stringData 
                                          options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments 
                                            error:nil];
```

**UPDATE**

You can create an NSDictionary witch will have the same structure of your JSON then create a string from this dictionary with JSON representation

> To generate a JSON string from a NSDictionary or NSArray, you do not need to import any third party framework anymore.

Here is how to do it:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryOrArrayToOutput = // Here you will construct your dictionary
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryOrArrayToOutput 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass kNilOptions if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: this code verify the string in json format. am create json sting only.

Comment: i don't really understand what you trying to do

Comment: I have this problem . here is the reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057281/creating-json-format-in-objective-c