# The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value for key in object around character 16.)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is my sample code

```
 project = @"Project";
      projectId=@"ProjectID";
      issue =@"Issue";
      issueId=@"IssueID";
      activity =@"Activity";
      activityId=@"ActivityID";
      comment =@"Comment";
      entryID = @"EntryID";
      NSMutableDictionary *entryUser = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [entryUser setObject:@"5" forKey:common_Id];
      [entryUser setObject:@"Divya Bharathi" forKey:common_Name];

       NSMutableDictionary *sdetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       NSMutableArray *time_entry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //  NSMutableArray

      //self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      NSString *strHours,*wkDay;
      for(int i=0;i < [self.dataArray count] ;i++)
      {        
        NSDictionary *dataDic = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
       NSMutableDictionary *projectDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [projectDic setObject:[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:projectId] forKey:common_Id];
      [projectDic setObject:[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:project] forKey:common_Name];

      NSMutableDictionary *issueDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [issueDic setObject:[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:issueId] forKey:common_Id];

      NSMutableDictionary *activityDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [activityDic setObject:[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:activityId] forKey:common_Id];
      [activityDic setObject:[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:activity] forKey:common_Name];


            for (int j=0; j<7; j++) {
                  wkDay=@"";strHours =@"";
                  wkDay = self.wkDateArray[i];
                 strHours = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:wkDay]];
                  if(strHours.length)
                  {
                        [sdetails setObject:[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:entryID] forKey:common_Id];
                        [sdetails setObject:projectDic forKey:project];
                        [sdetails setObject:issueDic forKey:issue];
                        [sdetails setObject:entryUser forKey:currentUser];
                        [sdetails setObject:activityDic forKey:activity];
                        [sdetails setObject:strHours forKey:@"hours"];
                        [sdetails setObject:[dataDic objectForKeyedSubscript:comment] forKey:comment];
                        [sdetails setObject:wkDay forKey:@"spent_on"];
                        [time_entry addObject:sdetails];                        
                  }

                  }
      }

      NSMutableDictionary *results = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [results setObject:time_entry forKey:@"entries"];
      [results setObject:entryUser forKey:currentUser];
      [results setObject:@"2016-01-17" forKey:@"startday"];
      [results setObject:@"New" forKey:@"status"];
      [results setObject:@"0.0" forKey:@"total"];

      NSMutableDictionary *wktime = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [wktime setObject:results forKey:@"time"];


 NSString *jsonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",wktime];
      NSError *jsonError;
      NSData *requestData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

      NSLog(@"Json Data : %@",jsonData);
      NSLog(@"Error Values: %@",jsonError);
```

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value for key in object around
>   character 16.) UserInfo=0x7feb58f21b90 {NSDebugDescription=No value
>   for key in object around character 16.}

Comment: Show the string you're trying to decode.

Comment: Never mind the previous comment.  The reason it's failing is because you're storing the `description` of an `NSDictionary` as a string and expecting it to be valid JSON.  It's not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057281/creating-json-format-in-objective-c.

Comment: Do you understand what I wrote?

Answer (score 2):

As Avi pointed out,

```
  NSString *jsonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",wktime];
  NSData *requestData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

you have created a string and converted it into `NSData`, but later trying to use the `NSJSON` API to convert it into a dictionary, which will fail since the original string isnt json encoded.

You should just convert the dict into Data using the `NSJSON` API and just read back, although its use wont make much sense till you tell the context.

```
  NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: wktime options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
   NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

If you are trying to do a web request, i would suggest reading AFNetworking docs, that API is well built and can help a lot for web requests.